# Postgresql Error: Corrupt ascii-armor

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgcrypto

I am using **PostgreSQL 9.3.5**
 and trying to encrypt data using `pgp_pub_encrypt()` offered by `pgcrypto` extension. Running `SELECT pgp_pub_encrypt('Vipin', dearmor('gpg_public_key'))` throws an error **Corrupt ascii-armor**. Please help.

I am using

Comment: Well, `'gpg_public_key'` isn't a valid public key. Please show the exact query you actually ran.

Comment: @CraigRinger Here is the public key that I am using to encrypt the data, generated using GnuPG http://pastiebin.com/547c6c7e3d6b9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the entire key into pgp_pub_encrypt parameter like this :

```
SELECT pgp_pub_encrypt('Vipin', dearmor('-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=JkLD
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----'));
```